# How to create WordPress page with multiple URLs?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, seo

Is it possible to create a WordPress page with multiple URLs?

I want one URL per section, all without having duplicate content in SEO.

We don't want to use anchors because they don't have individual rankings like URLs.

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect users who visit `link1` and `link2` both to `link1`?

Comment: URL has to remain unchanged, so JavaScript can read the URL and navigate to it's respective section based on URL path.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Could you please edit your question and add what are you trying to achieve, and most importantly, why. Use examples and be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: But URLs are based on actual pages. So the page will have a URL of `/about` and that's what crawlers will see. If you create a script that sends visitors of `/about-jobs` to a certain section within the page, the URL doesn't exist in the same way that a crawler sees `/about`.

Anyway, how are you formatting the new links, as they will need to all follow the same structure. You will also need `id`'s on each section.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of plugins that can easily create URLs in bulk for you. I recommend [MPG: Multiple Pages Generator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-pages-generator-by-porthas/) because you can customize the content of each page to avoid duplicate content and it's incredibly easy to manage all of your new pages once they’re created.

You just need to have all your products and their variable data in a CSV file and a template page. The plugin creates shortcodes for the information from your file and you just need to add those shortcodes to a template page, like:

Visit us at {{mpg_location}}

The best thing is that if you want to edit anything from your CSV or template page, you can do that anytime. Find out more about it here: https://mpg.porthas.com